# How avoid automatic change of months on Keith Wood datepick calendar plugin

Tags: jquery, calendar

I'm currently using Keith Wood datepick calendar plugin, the calendar displays 2 months ( that what I need, so it's okay) but when I press a day thats on the calendar on the right, the entire 2 calendar move, and now I see 2 other months.

So if I see NOVEMBER ( calendar on the left) - DECEMBER (calendar on the right), I click on Decemeber 15th, the calendar changes to DECEMBER - JANUARY.

Is there any way I can change that behaviour? Thank you in advance

Comment: Aside from the issue I'd suggest not using the Keith Wood libraries. They are very old now and the code quality is highly questionable. I'd strongly suggest finding an alternative which meets your needs.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately is the only one that meets the requerimients for a project and I'm having a really hard time finding one that has the same options (For free) It's a project for school

Answer (score 0):

Use Keith Wood's `onSelect` event so when you click on the date it goes back to -1 month without even showing the switch to +1 month:

```
$(function() {
    $('#popupDatepicker').datepick({ 
    rangeSelect: true, monthsToShow: 2, onSelect: function(dates) { $('#popupDatepicker').datepick('changeMonth', -1); }, showTrigger: '#calImg'});
  
});
```

here is my codepen:
https://codepen.io/tadaspuleikis/pen/zYdexdw

Comment: Hello, thank you! it works as a solution!

Comment: If this answers your issue then don't forget to mark this answer as "answered".